# adjust the image size in puzzle game

Tags: java

I tried to find in which part of code, does it crop my picture, so if I set picture with res 1200x2000 I get part of it, why is that?

Code from : http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/puzzle/

Here is full code:

```
public class Puzzle extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;
    private Image source;
    private Image image;
    int[][] pos;
    int width, height;

    public Puzzle() {

        pos = new int[][] {
                            {0, 1, 2}, 
                            {3, 4, 5}, 
                            {6, 7, 8}, 
                            {9, 10, 11}
                        };


        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4, 0, 0));

        ImageIcon sid = new ImageIcon(Puzzle.class.getResource("icesid.jpg"));
        source = sid.getImage();

        width = sid.getIconWidth();
        height = sid.getIconHeight();


        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)), BorderLayout.NORTH);    
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

 ****** HERE IS circumcision: *********
        for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if ( j == 2 && i == 3) {
                    label = new JLabel("");
                    centerPanel.add(label);
                } else {
                    button = new JButton();
                    button.addActionListener(this);
                    centerPanel.add(button);
                    image = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(source.getSource(),
                        new CropImageFilter(j*width/3, i*height/4, 
                            (width/3)+1, height/4)));
                    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                }
            }
        }

        setSize(325, 275);
        setTitle("Puzzle");
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Puzzle();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        Dimension size = button.getSize();

        int labelX = label.getX();
        int labelY = label.getY();
        int buttonX = button.getX();
        int buttonY = button.getY();
        int buttonPosX = buttonX / size.width;
        int buttonPosY = buttonY / size.height;
        int buttonIndex = pos[buttonPosY][buttonPosX];



        if (labelX == buttonX && (labelY - buttonY) == size.height ) {

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex + 3;

             centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(label, buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);
             centerPanel.validate();
        }

        if (labelX == buttonX && (labelY - buttonY) == -size.height ) {

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex - 3;
             centerPanel.remove(labelIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);
             centerPanel.add(label, buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.validate();
        }

        if (labelY == buttonY && (labelX - buttonX) == size.width ) {

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex + 1;

             centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(label, buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);
             centerPanel.validate();
        }

        if (labelY == buttonY && (labelX - buttonX) == -size.width ) {

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex - 1;

             centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(label, labelIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);
             centerPanel.validate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a CropImageFilter, that is probably it.

Comment: I saw that, it have formula to calculate proper size for piece of button? I don't think that is problem?

Answer (score 0):

image = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(source.getSource(),
                        new CropImageFilter(j*width/3, i*height/4, 
                            (width/3)+1, height/4)));

ok I didn't pay attention to it.
this should be your problem, you always set the size to 325*275!
    setSize(325, 275);

Comment: Like i comment up...  saw that, that  have formula to calculate proper size for piece of button? I don't think  that is problem?

Comment: what about this one?  setSize(325, 275);